Enter Malaysia on dual citizenship (NOT including Malaysian)
I heard that Malaysia is a strict single-nationality recognition country. Even if you have two passports (NOT including Malaysian), you can only choose one nationality to visit this county. For example, if you visited with a British passport for the first time, then in the future you can only use the British nationality. The Malaysian government only recognises the first nationality you use.
My wife is a dual passport holder (British & Chinese), and we are planning to visit KL from Bangkok in August. But she visited Malaysia once before with her British passport. Would it be a problem if she only used her Chinese passport to enter and exit Malaysia this time? Both passports are now visa-free. She used both passports in Singapore and Thailand without any problem.

Is there a particular reason why she doesn't want to just keep using her British passport?

the reason is she ganna travel to shanghai then bkk then kl. so bring one passport is enough for all visa free purpose.

@sniper2006 That's fine, her Chinese passport is enough

Malaysia is very strict about nationality for Malaysian citizens: it does not tolerate dual nationality and will cancel their Malaysian citizenship if they're caught with another passport.
However, this is irrelevant to non-Malaysians, I personally have entered Malaysia with passports from two different countries and never had any problems.  YMMV, but I would be astonished if there was any rule against this (why would there be?).

They've clearly been given some BS advice by someone


Even if you have two passports (NOT including Malaysian), you can only choose one nationality to visit this county. For example, if you visited with a British passport for the first time, then in the future you can only use the British nationality. The Malaysian government only recognises the first nationality you use.

This is NOT true, in fact no country does this, so whoever told you so either doesn't know what they're talking about, or got lost in translation due to shortcomings in English proficiency.
So no, your wife can enter and exit with either passport, though it should be the same for entry and exit.


Would it be a problem if she only used her Chinese passport to enter and exit Malaysia this time?

Hard to tell. They may not like it and give you a hard time. I don't think they would refuse entry though. Requiring the same citizenship for all future visit would permanently ban anyone from entering who changes citizenship without becoming dual, which seems unlikely.
The basic rule for dual+ passport holders: if both work, use the one that's most likely to get you through immigration quickly and smoothly. That's in your case the UK passport, so that's what you should be using unless you have a really strong reason not to.
Note, that you can easily switch passports between countries. If you entered Singapore with your Chinese passport and want to go to Malaysia you would show your Chinese passport and Singapore exit control and your UK passport at Malaysian entry control.

Doubt that. Your wife can enter with either passport. It is just that if she enter with Chinese passport, she must exit with the same passport.
